# ACM International Collegiate Programming Contest Asia Regional D Henry

Tags: c++, algorithm

Given a fraction `a / b`, where `a` and `b` are positive integers and `a < b`, choose the largest unit fraction `1 / x_1` such that  `1 / x_1 <= a / b`. Then subtract `1 / x_1` from `a / b`, and repeat the process for the remainder: choose the largest unit fraction `1 / x_2` such that  `1 / x_2 <= (a / b) - (1 / x_1)`. Repeat again until there is no remainder. This procedure will result in a series of unit fractions  `1 / x_1, 1 / x_2, 1 / x_3, ...` that sum up to the given fraction `a / b`. This procedure always terminates for any input fraction `a / b` with a finite number of distinct unit fractions. Write a program that prints out the denominator of the last fraction in the resulting series.

#### Example:

```
5/7 = 1/2 + 1/5 + 1/70
```

**Sample input:**

```
3 
4 23
5 7
8 11
```

**Output:**

```
138
70
4070
```

**Code:**

My code is for C++ language

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;
int testCase;
double a;
double son;
double mom;

int main()
{
    ifstream file("input.txt");
    file >> testCase;

    while (testCase--)
    {
        file >> son;
        file >> mom;

        while (son != 1)
        {
            a = (int)(mom / son) + 1;
            son = (son * a) - mom;
            mom = mom * a;
        }
        cout << mom << endl;
    }
    file.close();
}
```

I think my algorithm is correct, but my school grading system says it is exceeding the runtime limit. I don't know why.

Comment: `son` probably gets ery close to `1`, but not quite exactly equal to `1`. You might need to compare it to a small range (like `abs(son - 1.0) < 0.0001` or something. Use a debugger to step through the code line by line to check.

Comment: thank you for your advice and edit it helps a lot

Answer (score 1):

You probably forgot to divide `mom` and `son` by their greatest common divisor (GCD) at each step. This can probably let certain examples run forever or longer than expected. Check if this is the problem. Also, why do you use `double` type for `son` and `mom`? The numerator and denomenator of a fraction are supposed to be integers. If they can be very big integers, just use `unsigned long int` or `size_t` (synonymous in c++). The `double` data type does not have so many significant digits as `size_t`.

Comment: thank you for your advice. after process GCD it solves the problem and i will change variable type thank you